# Converting hex value to utf-8 character

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, hex, imap

I'm using IMAP class to read emails. When my mail body contains Ö IMAP returns the hex value: `=C3=96`. How do I convert it to an utf-8 Ö?

I'm thinking something like :

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8);
System.Byte[] ch = new System.Byte[1];

ch[0] = System.Convert.ToByte([hex value of Ö], 16);
var decodedItem = enc.GetString(ch);
```

Where expected value of decodedItem is Ö. But I don't really know why Ö translates to `=C3=96` in IMAP and I can't send that in to `ToByte()` because `=C3=96` isnt a true hex value.

I've also tried doing this:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8);
System.Byte[] ch = new System.Byte[1];

ch[0] = 214;
var decodedItem = enc.GetString(ch);
```

But the value in decodedItem is = �

Comment: It already is utf-8.  But encoded as text instead of bytes.  That encoding is called [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).  Now you know what to google, ".net decode quoted-printable text".  First hit is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That symbol is actually two bytes (0xC3, 0x96), but you're only assigning one, and a different one at that (214 = 0xD6)...

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
System.Byte[] ch = { 0xC3, 0x96 };

var decodedItem = enc.GetString(ch);
```

To clarify a bit further, 0xD6 (214) is actually for Unicode, not UTF-8, and you'd reach it by changing the call and values to match the Unicode value:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Unicode");
System.Byte[] ch = { 0xD6, 0x00 };
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/
U+00D6  Ö   c3 96   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS

This means you have to take away the '=' and then convert it to UTF 8

I hope this helps.

Greetings Alex

Answer (score 1):

There's no Unicode in most of today's e-mails. In order to arrive to a Unicode text, you have to do the following operations:

- Find a textual part of the message. There could be many of them. See the `BODYSTRUCTURE` in RFC 3501.
- Inspect the MIME headers (or the `BODYSTRUCTURE` response) to find out the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` of the part that you're looking at. Most common encodings are `quoted-printable` and `base64`. Look at RFC 2045, 2046, 2047 and 2048 for details.
- Undo the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` so that you arrive at a bytestream which contains a sequence of bytes.
- Look at the `Content-Type` header, the `charset` parameter.
- Decode the stream of bytes using a codec/charset/... which you find above.
- Congratulations, you now have your Unicode string.

Alternatively, use a library which implements these functions in your favorite language/framework. There are plenty of them.